# Custom sort-order with SQL-Server and .NET Entity-Framework

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, sorting

I have a table I store contacts and their phones.
*Contact*: ContactId (int, PK), FirstName (varchar), LastName (varchar)
*Phone*: PhoneId (int, PK), ContactId(int FK), Number (varchar), SortOrder (tinyint)

I want that under each contact, the user should be able to maintain the priority of the phones, meaning that the SortOrder column of phone should be under each ContactId by consecutive numbers.

For exmple, when adding the first phone to a user, its SortOrder should become 1, for the second 2 and so on.

Say the user added 5 phone to a user, now he wants to move phone (with order) 3 to place 2, it should push current 2 to place 3 and vice versa.

If he want to make phone 1 to last it should 'pull' all the phones' SortOrder by -1, then assign previous 1 to 5.

I want this system to be consistent and not to have open edges where I have:

- 2 phones with identical sort-order values in one group
- First phone in group with value higher than 1
- Last phone in group with value higher or smaller than amount of phones in group
- etc. etc. etc.

I think I am pretty clear so far (am I).

Now my question is, considering I retrieve the data with .NET EF in a desktop app, and I will be accessing the phones using the Contact.Phones navigation property.

Should implement this system in the DAL or in server `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` trigger?
I personally think this has to be implemented on the server, cuz imagine different users play around with the same contact-phones at the same time, this might break the consistency, huh?

Any tips, links, code, advice jokes regarding this custom-sorting issue will be welcommed.

I also thought about ROWNUMBER() as a good idea of retrieving the data, but I need to maintain the sorting, not only selecting it.

Notes:
In general I asked the question in continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923009/need-advice-in-designing-tables-in-sql-server/1923106#1923106) answer, I decided to use, the contact-phone example was just to make things simple.
I've found [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1499127&page=5) post discussing my issue but no technical advise was provided there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your square pegging a round hole here.

Your answer CAN be as easy as Contact.Phones.OrderBy ( @p => @p.SortOrder ) then taking care of all of your phones in a Contact.SetPhone( phone, order ) method which can encompass whatever custom logic you wish.

Also since this is business and view logic your persistence store shouldn't be aware of whats going on.

Comment: I have the feeling that you didn't read the question and my considerations, I do want to do it in SQL to avoind unnessary selects for the bulks needed to updated.
Besides, could you update your question and elaborate the SetPhone thingy; how will retrieve the 'order' parameter of it?

Comment: I did read it.  I'm just unsure where these selects are coming from.  If you have a collection of contacts, update all the sort orders, and then save your changes EntityFramework will just spit out Update statements.

Comment: Let's say I have a contact with 30 phones (in this example it's kind of rediculus, in my application I use something that has many records in each group). I get the Contact thru EF without it's phones, then I add a new phone with SortOrder = 5, I want that the server should do the job for me and push the following records' SortOrder +=1, so I don't need to reload the group and save it, this is just an unnecessary round-trip + data transfer.